# Explain to obtain the query time?

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

I trying to use command `Explain` to obtain the query time of my mySql database, however it return always 0.00sec, am i misunderstand the Explain command usage in mySql?

Below is my command:

```
mysql> explain select * from table;
```

0.00 sec

```
mysql> select * from table;
```

15 sec

why the explain wouldn't return the same query time result as i using the same command?

Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Explain is completely different.
It never runs a query. But just tells how it would be run.

Comment: so how do i optimize my database this command? since i nvr get the query time